# Handling Hierarchy Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I have

```
Name          Company Nr       Mother Company Nr
Company A        100                 
Company B        101                 100
Company C        102                 100
Company D        103                 102
Company E        104                 100
```

in a BusinessObject that I extracted from an XML document

I need to show this in a Hierarchy Mode, and looking through MSDN I found the [IHierarchicalEnumerable Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ihierarchicalenumerable.aspx), but I can't figure it out how to work with it.

my Hierarchy object is

```
// A collection of FileSystemHierarchyData objects
public class FileSystemHierarchicalEnumerable : ArrayList, IHierarchicalEnumerable
{
   public FileSystemHierarchicalEnumerable()
      : base()
   {
   }

   public IHierarchyData GetHierarchyData(object enumeratedItem)
   {
      return enumeratedItem as IHierarchyData;
   }
}
```

and I need to populate it, right?

I doing something like:
    void getHierarchy(System.Collections.Generic.List companies)
    {
       FileSystemHierarchicalEnumerable h = new FileSystemHierarchicalEnumerable();

```
   foreach (CompanyHierarchy c in companies)
   {
      if (!h.Contains(c.CompanyNumber))
         h.Add(c);
   }
}
```

how do I ADD in the right Hierarchy ... where do I add what level it is, how do I get **Company E** to be added under **Company A** ?

I'm really strugling here, and even if I see that could be easy to get this, I can't figure it out :(

I really need help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[this might help you understand it](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/IHierarchySupport.aspx)